# Maxima and minima where $f$ is not differentiable

Tags: calculus, monotone-functions

I've a question on the study of the monotony of a function.

There is this theorem:

> Let $f(x)$ differentiable in a interval $I$ and $f'(x_0)=0$ (with $x_0
> \in I$).
>
> If $f'(x)\geq 0$ from the left of $x_0$ and $f'(x)\leq 0$ from the
>   right of $x_0$, then $x_0$ is a maximum point for the function $f(x)$. (In the opposite case it is a minimum point).

When I'm looking for the points of maxima and minima for the function I must check also the points in which $f'(x)$ is not differentiable.

What I wonder is: in that case is it correct to say that

> Let $f(x)$ differentiable in a interval $I-\big\{x_0\big\}$ (with $x_0
>  \in I$).
>
> If $f'(x)\geq 0$ from the left of $x_0$ and $f'(x)\leq 0$ from the
>   right of $x_0$, then $x_0$ is a maximum point for the function $f(x)$. (In the opposite case it is a minimum point).

?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

This is not the case. Take, for example, $f(x)=x$ for $x<0$, $f(x)=-x+1$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=1/2$.

You will need, at least, continuity on $x_0$ (and continuity con $x_0$ plus differentiability on $I$ implies continuity on $I$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot to mention that I was implying continuity in $x_0$ (and differentiability in $I-\big \{ x_0 \big \}$). Is it valid in that case?